# Augmenting Android voice dictionary

Tags: android

The voice recognition seems to have a static dictionary; which is in contrast to the text dictionary that adapts to words we use. This causes problems when dictating an uncommon name on the phone (`Aibin` becomes `I've been`, for example) which gives unsalvagable results.

Can we programatically alter the voice dictionary to tune into contact names? What is the capability across Android versions?